# Как добавить страницу в админку, но не добавлять в меню?

Tags: wordpress

Знаю как добавить страницу в админку: add_submenu_page или add_menu_page. Но возможно ли добавить страницу в админку без вывода страницы в списке меню?
В моём случае хочу добавить страницу редактирования для записи в таблице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы спрятать ссылку пункта подменю из основного меню админ-панели, используйте первый параметр `null` или `options.php`:

```php
// Прячем страницу из меню, но она все равно будет рабочей
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page');
function register_my_custom_submenu_page(){
    add_submenu_page(
        null,  //или 'options.php'
        'Произвольная страница подменю',
        'Произвольная страница подменю',
        'manage_options',
        'my-custom-submenu-page',
        'my_custom_submenu_page_callback'
    );
}
```

Подробнее: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_submenu_page